# How to retrieve values from node-oracledb toQueryStream() as a Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-oracledb

While trying to get the rows from `resultSet` using `toQueryStream()` I can only find the rows in console. But not able to return value using promises as `toQueryStream()` function uses `eventListener` to resolve rows. My code is given below please suggest to get the row values.

```
function getPosCounter() {
    return oracledb.getConnection(kcdConnStr)
        .then(function (conn) {
            return conn.execute(`BEGIN GETPOSCOUNTER(:CV_1); END;`, { // EXECUTE ORACLE PROCEDURE
                CV_1: { dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.CURSOR } //CURSOR DEFINED FOR OUT PARAM
            })
                .then((result) => {
                    var resRows = new Array();
                    var resultSet = result.outBinds.CV_1; //RESULT SET FOR OUTPUT
                    var queryStream = resultSet.toQueryStream(); //QUERYSTREAM INITIALIZED FOR CURSOR VALUES
                    var consumeStream = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        queryStream.on('data', function (row) {
                            console.log(row);
                        });
                        queryStream.on('error', reject);
                        queryStream.on('close', resolve);
                    })
                        .then(rows => {
                            console.dir(rows); //RETURN ROW VALUES 
                        });

                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    conn.close();
                    console.error(err);
                    return 'failure';
                })
        });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you wouldn't just use resultSet.getRows() which already returns a promise for you?

Comment: Another question... I get that you want getPosCounter to return a promise, but are you able/open to changing the code in the function to use async/await? This would greatly simplify the logic. If you're open to it, I could try to mock something up for you.

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga the result set from the Stored Procedure is returning multiple rows and I was sure that it will get the result if I resolve it by `Promise.all`. But in that case the program may take a bit longer time to execute(as I am not sure about the execution time for `Promise.All` in compare to `nodejs-Stream`). Please advice if I'm not correct.

Comment: @DanMcGhan you are correct that I want to retrieve couple of rows of records from The mentioned oracle stored procedure and I just followed the instruction as mentioned in the document provided by Oracle Community to get return data from the result set. I have already solved it my way using the `nodejs-Stream` feature which provided me all `data-rows` in `json` format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before this issue I faced, I was not aware about the `nodeJs-Stream` feature which is quiet difficult to understand for me. So I found a documentation on Oracle Community about getting the rows from result set. Make it possible in the below way.

```
function getPosCounter() {
    return oracledb.getConnection(kcdConnStr)
        .then(function (conn) {
            return conn.execute(`BEGIN USP_POSCOUNTER(:CV_1); END;`, { // EXECUTE ORACLE PROCEDURE
                CV_1: { dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.CURSOR } //CURSOR DEFINED FOR OUT PARAM
            })
                .then((result) => {
                    var resRows = [];
                    var resultSet = result.outBinds.CV_1; //RESULT SET FOR OUTPUT
                    var queryStream = resultSet.toQueryStream(); //QUERYSTREAM INITIALIZED FOR CURSOR VALUES
                    return consumeStream = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        queryStream.on('data', (row) => {
                            resRows.push(row); //STORE ROWS IN TO BLANK ARRAY 
                        });
                        queryStream.on('error', reject);
                        queryStream.on('close', () => {
                            resolve(resRows); //RETURN ON RESOLVING ALL THE ROWS
                            conn.close();
                        });
                    });
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    conn.close();
                    //console.error(err);
                    return 'failure';
                })
        });
}
```

Comment: Why not just use a ResultSet and call [`getRows()`](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/resultset2.js#L64-L70)?  (This will be even simpler in the [next node-oracledb release](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/commit/f6d9792cc358a95e0ceaa9d2a361229e856fa90d), since you won't even have to loop over `getRows()`).

Comment: @ChristopherJones thanks for the advice and will implement the same and let you know for further. Thanks again for your advice. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fiddling with promises and streams, you could code like this:

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
const dbConfig = require('./dbconfig.js');

if (process.platform === 'darwin') {
  oracledb.initOracleClient({libDir: process.env.HOME + '/Downloads/instantclient_19_8'});
}

async function run() {
  let connection;

  try {

    connection = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig);

    await connection.execute(
      `create or replace procedure usp_poscounter(p out sys_refcursor) as
       begin
         open p for select postal_code from locations order by location_id;
       end;`);

    const r = await getPosCounter();
    console.dir(r, { depth: null });

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      try {
        await connection.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}

async function getPosCounter() {

  let conn;

  try {
    conn = await oracledb.getConnection(dbConfig); // should really use a pool instead

    const result = await conn.execute(
      `BEGIN USP_POSCOUNTER(:CV_1); END;`,
      { CV_1: { dir: oracledb.BIND_OUT, type: oracledb.CURSOR } }
    );

    let row, outRows = [];
    while ((row = await result.outBinds.CV_1.getRow())) {
      outRows.push(row);
    }

    // With node-oracledb 5.2 you will be able to simplify this loop to be the
    // following one line.  Note with any node-oracledb version, if the number
    // of rows is large, then you will want your architecture to deal with
    // batches of rows insteading of returning one big array.
    //
    // const outRows = await result.outBinds.CV_1.getRows();  // empty arg gets all rows

    return (outRows);

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (conn) {
      try {
        await conn.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}

run();
```